# Assigning functionality to a image using video feed as input

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

as a semester project me and my group had to create a game. We decided to make a 2D racing game, how is it different from a normal 2D racing game is that we use image processing to control the cars. The camera detects the users hands and based on their location it moves the car. So far we were able to do most of the code, except one part..

My question is, how do we assign the image (car) functionality based on the location of the hand.

We are using OpenCV, and it did everything so far, but as for functionality to the image, we couldnt figure anything out. I heard that SDL is very good when trying to make a 2D game such as this but I couldnt make it work with OpenCV.

I need suggestions on how to assign functionality to an image OR maybe change the image into something else sprite/object making it easier to assign functionality. I am open to any suggestions. I have tried doing this using only OpenCV/C++ methods, such as waitkey and mouse events but they will not work when we need the data from the video input.

Thank you

Comment: On each frame, if the hand movement is left, steer the sprite left.  If right, then right, etc.  It sounds like you've already implemented the hard bit, so the rest should be pretty much independent to your opencv stuff, you're just controlling it with data from your existing code, rather than keyboard inputs.

Comment: Yeah so the last thing my code does is print out the coordinates (x and y) for the center of the hand. I have the car image loaded to a background (image is loaded as Mat). But from here i do not know how to put everything together, assign some values to the coordinates (if hand is in left corner => car should turn left, etc.) and then based on those coordinates move the cars. If you could be a bit more explicit it would be a big help. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: There are a million and one sites with gamedev tutorials - just follow one of those until you've got a basic game that works using the cursor keys, then replace the bit that does keyboard input with your function to read the hand position, and you'll be done

Comment: Also, make sure your camera code works at an "interactive" speed - e.g. if you just run it in a loop, printing out your x and y values, how many do you get a second?  If it's significantly less than 30 then you'll find your game won't be particularly playable

Comment: well it seems this is about scene rendering/presentation and not about image processing at all :) may be you should change the title and tags so the right people see it and help. also you did not specify if it is 3D or 2D car simulation,... 1st person view or top view or any view and much much more ... For the driving part you want to implement car wheel and levers or just the hand position like stick ?